# How do I asycronously update a UI element from a ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, async-await

I am using a label on multiple forms which display the weather data which is called from a WCF service. I wish to have this update every minute to display the updated weather data without interfering with user interaction.

I get the following error:

> "Must create DependencySource on same Thread as the DependencyObject. "

I have a View Model for getting the weather data asynchronously which inherits from ViewModelBase to handle property changed events. The properties from the ViewModel are bound to the label

ViewModel for weather

```
public class WeatherDataVM : ViewModelBase
{
    private string _windString;
    private SolidColorBrush _windState;
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;


    public WeatherDataVM()
    {
        _timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Render);
        _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
        _timer.Tick += async (sender, args) => {await Task.Run(() => GetWindAsync()); };
        //_timer.Tick += _timer_Tick;
        _timer.Start();
        GetWind();
    }

    private void GetWind()
    {
        var weatherFromService = Services.Instance.EmptyStackService.GetWeather();
        var windSpeed = Convert.ToDouble(weatherFromService.Windspeed);
        var maxGust = Convert.ToDouble(weatherFromService.Max_Gust_In_Last_Min);

        var windSpeedMPH = Math.Round(windSpeed * 1.15078, 1);
        var maxGustMPH = Math.Round(maxGust * 1.15078, 1);

        var windString = $"W/S: {windSpeedMPH}({maxGustMPH})";

        var windState = new Color();
        if (windSpeed >= 40)
            windState = Color.FromRgb(255, 64, 64);
        else if (windSpeed >= 24)
            windState = Color.FromRgb(255, 212, 128);
        else
            windState = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);
        _windState = new SolidColorBrush(windState);

        _windString = windString;


    }

    private async Task GetWindAsync()
    {
        var weatherFromService = Services.Instance.EmptyStackService.GetWeather();
        var windSpeed = Convert.ToDouble(weatherFromService.Windspeed);
        var maxGust = Convert.ToDouble(weatherFromService.Max_Gust_In_Last_Min);

        var windSpeedMPH = Math.Round(windSpeed * 1.15078, 1);
        var maxGustMPH = Math.Round(maxGust * 1.15078, 1);

        var windString = $"W/S: {windSpeedMPH}({maxGustMPH})";

        var windState = new Color();
        if (windSpeed >= 40)
            windState = Color.FromRgb(255, 64, 64);
        else if (windSpeed >= 24)
            windState = Color.FromRgb(255, 212, 128);
        else
            windState = Color.FromRgb(0, 255, 0);

        WindState = new SolidColorBrush(windState);
        WindString = windString;

    }


    public string WindString
    {
        get { return _windString; }

        set
        {
            if (_windString == value)
                return;
            _windString = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("WindString");
        }
    }

    public SolidColorBrush WindState
    {
        get { return _windState; }

        set
        {
            if (_windState == value)
                return;
            _windState = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("WindState");
        }

    }
}
```

ViewModelBase

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml on view for label

```
<Label x:Name="lblWeather" Content="{Binding WindString}" Foreground="black" Background="{Binding WindState}" Style="{DynamicResource SmallLabel}"  />
```

code behind view in constructor

```
lblWeather.DataContext = new WeatherDataVM();
```

the weather label should change each time the timer ticks. Instead it throws an error.

Comment: Looks like you're attempting to update UI on a non UI thread, which will error because UI has thread affinity. You should await a Task lt t gt  where t contains data you need for the UI. Then update the ui, back on the ui thread.

Comment: You should remove `SolidColorBrush` from your `ViewModel` and use numbers or string instead, then apply a colour through a style or a converter. Then you can retrieve information however you want. This is why having UI elements in ViewModel is a bad idea, it always bites back!

Comment: SolidColorBrush  is not a UI element. It is a Freezable and as such explicitly designed to be created in a thread other than the UI thread. No problem at all with using it in a view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a brush on a background thread if you freeze it:

```
var brush = new SolidColorBrush(windState);
brush.Freeze();
WindState = brush;
```

But it doesn't make much sense to use a `DispatcherTimer` if you just call `Task.Run` in the `Tick` event handler.

Provided that your event handler only creates brushes and don't manipulate any UI elements directly (it certainly shouldn't since it's implemented in a view model), you could use a [System.Timer.Timer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8). Its `Elapsed` event is queued for execution on a thread pool thread where you can query the service without blocking the UI.